# Proper testing method for function in go

Tags: testing, go, md5

I'm new to go and started to play around with testing.
My method returns a []byte with a md5 hash in it.

```
func myHash(s string) []byte {
    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, s)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}
```

It's working and the hashes look ok, but when I'm testing it with this method:

```
func TestMyHash(t *testing.T) {
    s := "linux"
    bf := ("e206a54e97690cce50cc872dd70ee896")
    x := hashor(s)
    if !bytes.Equal(x, []byte(bf)) {
        t.Errorf("myHash ...")
    }
}
```

It will always fail. First I thought it could be some issue with the casting of a string to []byte or vice versa, but after trying ot over and over again I just need to ask here.

Can you give me an example how to test my function? Do I miss something necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The casted string are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably comparing the raw bytes of the hash with the hexadecimal formatted version of  a hash. You might want to do something like this:

```
got := fmt.Sprintf("%034x", myHash("linux"))
want := "00e206a54e97690cce50cc872dd70ee896"
if got != want {
    t.Errorf("got %q, want %q", got, want) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely overlooked that!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider marking the answer as solution if it has solved your problem. Thanks :)